# Facebook Chatheads in a Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

We already have a production Phonegap hybrid app. A new requirement is to implement a facebook's chatheads like overlay but I haven't find any plugin or documentation talking about this potential use-case with Cordova.

Is it possible to implement something like this using Phonegap? If I try the native implementation, Will I be able to link that with my Cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

[The Microsoft Ace plugin](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/) for Cordova provides APIs that allow for building features like this.

There's sadly no documentation on how to build Android overlays with the plugin right now so it'll take a bit of work to figure that part out, but it definitely seems to be possible.

http://microsoft.github.io/ace/